# Hiding subtotals in pivot table in epplus

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, epplus

I'm using EPPLUS to generate my pivot table ([see this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650080/epplus-pivot-tables-charts)).  I have the following code

```
//group by fields
foreach (string row in _GroupByColumns)
{
    ExcelPivotTableField field = pivotTable.Fields[row];

    //field formating
    field.Sort = eSortType.Ascending;
    field.Outline = false;
    field.Compact = false;
    field.ShowAll = false;
    field.SubtotalTop = false; //doesn't work, subtotals still there when excel is opened

    //doesn't work, will result in "unreadable content" error when Excel is opened
    //field.SubTotalFunctions = eSubTotalFunctions.None;

    //add it to the pivot
    pivotTable.RowFields.Add(field);
}
```

`_GroupByColumns` is a `List<string>` that contains my group by columns.

I thought `field.SubtotalTop = false;` would hide subtotals.  It doesn't.  `field.SubTotalFunctions = eSubTotalFunctions.None;` results in "invalid data" error when I open my Excel.  What else can I try?

Comment: Is this a workbook that will be reused or is the workbook regenerated every time you need to do this?

Comment: @jbarker2160 The database is queried and a new file is generated everyday.  I suppose I can have the C# code truncate and fill new data using a template, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: C# doesn't have the .Subtotals property of the PivotFields class.  You can either do it in VB.Net or VBA.  It's a known issue with MS.  The SubtotalTop only modifies the position of the subtotals in the chart (bottom vs top.)

Comment: @jbarker2160 What's the work-around for C# then?  Is there one?

Comment: The work around that I use is to remove the subtotals in VBA when the pivotcache is refreshed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I'm adding this answer in case anybody Googles here.

You need to set the SubTotalFunctions property *after* adding the field to the RowFields collection.  This is because adding it to the collection changes the XML node that SubTotalFunctions makes adjustments to.  This will work...

```
ExcelPivotTableField field = pivotTable.Fields[row];

pivotTable.RowFields.Add(field);//<-- ADD IT FIRST

//field formating
field.Sort = eSortType.Ascending;
field.Outline = false;
field.Compact = false;
field.ShowAll = false;
field.SubtotalTop = false;
field.SubTotalFunctions = eSubTotalFunctions.None;//<-- THIS WILL WORK NOW
```